# Xamarin Forms RowDefinition height binding via converter set height autoD

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

Currently I would like to bind my `Height` property on a `Rowdefinition` in a `Grid`. I want to show the row if the property `IsOnline` on my `ViewModel` is set to `true`.

Binding a number as `Height` is no problem at all, I am just wondering how I could bind it to `Auto`.

My View:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

My Converter `HeightConverter`:

```
public class HeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return "Auto";
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [GridLength Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.gridlength?view=xamarin-forms) it has properties like Auto, Star and etc. You could use those as return values from the `IValueConverter`.

Comment: `RowDefinition`'s height property got a `Auto` aswell. If I dont bind it, it works fine... In the binding, I cant use it.

Comment: So  when you return a GridLength.Auto from your converter it is not working? I don't get your last comment ...

Comment: Oh my bad, I somehow misunderstood your answer. Works fine now!

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer so it will be easier to understand what I meant.